# I have a route defined in my web.php but the error says throw new InvalidArgumentException("Route [{$name}] not defined.");

Tags: php, laravel, view, routes

View code is

```html
<h2>Receipt</h2>

<h3 class="pull-right">
    <a href="{{ route('pdfview/'.$donation_id,['download'=>'pdf']) }}">Download PDF</a>
</h3>
```

web.php code is

```php
Route::get('/pdfview/{id}',array('as'=>'pdfview','uses'=>'pdf_controller@pdfview'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are passing the path of route but not route name, and laravel route name does not work like that.

route('route-name',[array-of-parameters]);

as you named the route 'pdfview' so I believe the code for view code is

```
<a href="{{ route('pdfview',['id' => $donation_id, 'download'=>'pdf']) }}">Download PDF</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Simplest way to represent named routes in a link is

```
 <a href="{{ route('pdfview', [$id]) }}">Download PDF</a>
```

Laravel provides a global route() function that gets the URL to a named route. The first Parameter is the route name (string). Depending on the route you’re trying to access you may also need to pass in an array of parameters as the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

The [`route()` function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-route) expects a route name.

```html
<a href="{{ route('pdfview',['id'=> $donation_id]) }}">Download PDF</a>
```